# Problem: cannot calculate standard deviation!

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, variance, standard-deviation

I have a following question and struggling a bit.

> An insurance company holds a portfolio of 100 insurance cover plans. The average cost of each claim against the plan is 20 dollars with a standard deviation of 5 dollars.
>
> The company wants to set aside amount of money X, such that 95% of all claims are covered, how much would X to be?

Is it correct that first I do the following steps:

- 20*100 = 2000; to find a mean for distribution
- 5*100 = 500 to find the standard deviation of this distribution?

or should I calculate variance first:

- 5*5 = 25, then
- 25*100 = 2500, and then
- sqrt(2500) = 50 to find the stand.deviation?

Comment: label it as a home work

Comment: You need to think about the question and the information you are given more. You are given the average cost and standard deviation, what does that mean? What is the question asking you to find?